# Embedded spatial database for Java?

Tags: spatial-database, java

Are there any embedded spatial databases for Java? I've come across H2 Spatial, but it was difficult to tell the status of that and if it can be used as an embedded spatial database.

Comment: It looks like the embedded hsql db does what I need... http://www.mvnbrowser.com/artifact-details.html?groupId=org.geotools&artifactId=gt2-hsql

Comment: SpatiaLit http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=spatialite_tut01 also looks promising.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try Hatbox (http://hatbox.sourceforge.net/derbyquickstart.html) from the web page:

> Hatbox has two distinct parts: the core library and a Geotools DataStore. The core library can be used entirely independently of the Geotools DataStore. This quick start will use only the core library to get data into your new Hatbox spatialized table and to issue spatial queries on it. It will focus on using Hatbox with JavaDB (Sun's packaging of Apache Derby) simply because it comes as part of a Sun JDK 6 install.

Comment: I successfully used Hatbox with H2. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

[GeoDB](http://github.com/jdeolive/geodb) is exactly what you need. It's an extension to H2 based on JTS. There also is a Hibernate dialect for geodb (link updated) (http://www.hibernatespatial.org/hibernate-spatial-h2-geodb/).

Answer (score 0):

Look on JASPA for this

http://forge.osor.eu/projects/jaspa/

http://www.osor.eu/projects/jaspa

Links above from the announcement on http://www.listware.net/201007/postgresql-general/88038-general-jaspa-java-spatial-for-postgresql-and-h2-released.html

Some presentations about it at foss4g 2010 http://2010.foss4g.org/presentations_show.php?id=3661

Answer (score -1):

[H2 database](https://www.h2database.com) supports the Geometry type natively as of [version 1.3.173](https://www.h2database.com/html/changelog.html). An extension called  [H2GIS](http://www.h2gis.org) available on Maven Central gives full SFSQL support.

An extended documentation has been written on the website, but you should start from the [Quick-Start guide](http://www.h2gis.org/docs/dev/quickstart/)

Comment: The documentation for H2GIS is terrible though.  And try and find an example of someone using hibernate to use it.